# Remote Data Transfer Using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am looking to write an application that will take client data from a database, transfer it to our server application, manipulate that data and then pass it back to the client. I would like this to be as seamless as possible and as secure as possible. Also, the manipulation part of this could take several hours. The format of the data will be different for each client. To make the application as easy to maintain as possible, the simplest solution too.

What methods would people recommend for achieving this?

Comment: which db ? Connectivity between sites ?

Comment: What's the justification for going db -> client -> server -> client, if the processing takes place on the server? Is there any reason your server-side app can't pull the data directly from the database?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Classic-WTF-Rutherford,-Price,-Atkinson,-Strickland,-and-Associates-Dentistry,-Inc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF will make your implementation easy. It looks like you are wanting to have the client -> server -> client communication asynchronous, since the server process can take hours, you don't want to block your client that long.

You probably want to define a server WCF service contract to allow the clients to load data to the server. You also want a client side WCF service contract that the server can use to send the results back when the processing is completed. OR you can have the server send a small message to the client WCF service telling it that "results are ready, come and get them when you are ready". You will need to coordinate this with some type of ID; the server tells the client to use this id when it wants to collect the results.

Have a look for duplex, asynchronous and peer-to-peer communication topics in WCF. There should be plenty of examples if you google around.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) framework of .NET 4.0.

Comment: WCF was what I was looking at but there are still many different ways of doing it via WCF. I am currently reading about OData.

Answer (score 0):

- 1/backup the database in prod
- 2/download it,
- 3/restore in local
- 4/modify,
- 5/backup in local
- 6/upload
- 7/restore in prod

to download in https or sftp, with ip restriction
you can compress the database before download it too

Comment: WCF is a far superior method in my opinion.

Comment: Which is great unless you have multiple clients, or your database is large, or you have limited bandwidth, or you aren't allowed to install a database server on the client, or are subject to code review, or you don't want the client to have access to the entire database, ...